# Display names using matching ID from two tables and returning a name value from the one pool of names

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, join

I have two tables. Using SQL I want to find the names from the one pool of names. e.g.:

```
if foodid1 = foodID return foodName,
if foodid2 = foodID return foodName, 
if foodid3 = foodid return foodname
```

My tables look like:

```
food table               order table
FoodID   FoodName        OrderID   FoodID1   FoodID2    FoodID3
1         chicken           1        1         2           3         
2          fish             2        3         4           5         
3          lamb             3        1         3           2               
4          pie                                                      
5         steak
```

I want a query that returns a value something like:

```
OrderID    FoodID1   FooDID2   FoodID3
1          chicken   fish      lamb
2          lamb      pie       steak
3          chicken   lamb      fish
```

I can get it to display the related IDs and the first set of names but I get errors when I alter the code for more. Not sure on the correct syntax for this query.

```
SELECT [ORDER TABLE].OID, [ORDER TABLE].FID1, [FOOD TABLE].[Food Name], [ORDER TABLE].FID2
FROM [FOOD TABLE] INNER JOIN [ORDER TABLE] ON [FOOD TABLE].[FID] = [ORDER TABLE].[FID2];
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to join the `[order table]` on the `[food table]` thrice, once for each `FoodId`:

```
SELECT     o.[OrderId], f1.[Food Name], f2.[Food Name], f3.[Food Name]
FROM       [ORDER TABLE] o
INNER JOIN [FOOD TABLE] f1 ON o.[FoodId1] = f1.[FoodId]
INNER JOIN [FOOD TABLE] f2 ON o.[FoodId2] = f2.[FoodId]
INNER JOIN [FOOD TABLE] f3 ON o.[FoodId3] = f3.[FoodId]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are set on using that data structure, I recommend Mureinik's answer, as it definitely gives you the result you explicitly asked for. However, I am curious why you have set up your data with three different food_IDs. Ask yourself, are the following two orders different?

1) Steak, Chicken, Pie

2) Pie, Steak, Chicken

If the answer is no and you are able to modify your structure, I would recommend you leave the FoodTable as is, and set up the Order table like this:

```
OrderID|FoodID
1       1
1       2
1       3
2       3
2       4
2       5
3       1
3       3
3       2
```

Then your select query will look like this:

```
SELECT o.OrderID, f.FoodName
FROM [Order Table] o LEFT JOIN [Food Table] f ON o.FoodID = f.FoodID
```

Comment: the problem with this answer it that it excludes fields with a value of 0. I am trying to include where order.fid1 = 0 and order.fid1 = food.fid

Comment: What do you mean zero? Do you mean null?

Comment: if the cell is null, the cell is ignored, if the cell is ignored, then it fails to show the values from the rest of the row because it does not have values in all cells